# how to design cassandra (or another nosql) scheme?

Tags: performance, architecture, nosql, live

We are about to move a project on apache cassandra from test to pilot and as a rdbms team, we were propably missing something.

**Basic rules (or lessons learned):**

- be sure you have big or almost no data (nothing between)
- do not believe in extremely cheap storage (cheap or not expensive might be
  better)
- think of your primary key as it was a reverse index
- think of time (or another data creation order) as it was a row/clustering key
- forgot about 100% foreign keys whenewer you can
- sample if you can
- do not care about dups
- json and asynchronous time aggregation on client can make cpus more relaxed

**ETL:**

- sample history if you can (or sample it just for reporting usage on separate reporting cluster)
- single threaded data streams spreaded over couple of servers will come in hand
- if you can afford asynchronous processing you can profit from knowledge of data patterns
- throw scrap data away (horizontaly and vertically) - or it will mislead BI people or even board members in worse case
- do not care about dups

The question is am I still missing something?
Are there another ways to achieve even better performance?